# How do I most efficiently narrow my selection of entities from a database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, select

I am using the following code to select every course from my a table with a bunch of courses - how would I change the code to narrow down the selection from every course to every course with the field db.Courses.myField = true?

```
var courses = from s in db.Courses
                select s;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple ...

```
var courses = from s in db.Courses
              where s.myField == true
              select s;
```

Take a look at the [data tutorials on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-%28data%29).

Comment: Thank you, still learning this and juggling the information around in my  head.  The help I receive here means a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq,

```
var courses = db.Courses.Where(s=>s.myField == true);
```